# Protecting html file in Android

Tags: android, html

I see a great tutorial for ios : [Protecting resources in iPhone and iPad apps](http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/07/protecting-resources/)

> Adding new resources to be encrypted should be quick and easy.
>
> The encryption process should be completely automatic during the build
> phase.
>
> Encrypted PDFs or HTML files must be useable in an embedded
> UIWebView
>
> Decryption must be in-memory and not create temporary
> unprotected files

How can we protect html in android like that

Comment: That technique is useless. Anyone who wants to can decrypt the HTML. Talented folk could do it in a matter of minutes. If you do not want the user to have access to something, then do not put it on their device.

Comment: Hi, i want to protect it from normal person. How can i protect html file in raw in android? Because my user can use my app offline!

Comment: A normal person cannot get at raw resources, assets, or other materials that you package in your APK.

Comment: They can extract my apk file. What's should i do?

Comment: Then you are not trying to protect it from a normal person. Anyone with the technical skills to "extract" your APK file can decrypt your encrypted content, or run a program that somebody else wrote that decrypts your encrypted content. I repeat: if you do not want the user to have access to something, then do not put it on their device.

Comment: so, my user can't use offline my app?

Comment: Well, they could intercept the downloaded HTML too, if they wanted to and were willing to set up the proxy software to do so. So, either do not write the app, or admit that some small percentage of people will actually be able to see your HTML. Bear in mind that out of the ~8 billion people on the planet, you are probably the only one who even *cares* about this HTML. As has been pointed out more times than I can count, your problem is not piracy, but obscurity.